# Why is UINT32_MAX + 1 = 0?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) 
{
    uint64_t a = UINT32_MAX;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    ++a;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    uint64_t b = (UINT32_MAX) + 1;
    std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;

    uint64_t c = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();

    std::cout << "c: " << c << std::endl;

    uint64_t d = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() + 1; 
    std::cout << "d: " << d << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```sh
a: 4294967295
a: 4294967296
b: 0
c: 4294967295
d: 0
```

Why are `b` and `d` both `0`? I cannot seem to find an explanation for this.

Comment: It's like when a clock is at `23:59:59` and one more second ticks by. The clock now reads `00:00:00`

Comment: Concerning `uint64_t b = (UINT32_MAX) + 1;`: `UINT32_MAX` is an `uint32_t`, 1 is of type `int`. This makes the `+` a 32 bit addition. Due to wrap-around you get 0 which is then (implicitly) converted to `(uint64_t)0`. (Similar for `uint64_t d = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() + 1;`)

Comment: Maybe you're confused because all your variables are `uint64_t` but that doesn't mean that the calculation on the right hand side will be 64 bit. That is still a 32 bit calculation which overflows as I indicated.

Comment: You may try instead: `uint64_t b = (UINT32_MAX) + (uint64_t)1;`. Making at least one argument a "larger" type will force the other to be implicitly converted (due to type promotion).

Comment: Thank you I was not aware that it would say Uint32_t + 1 and then to uint64_t thanks all and @john :p thanks XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is referred to as an overflow. `uint32_t` takes up 4 bytes or 32 bits of memory. When you use `UINT32_MAX` you are setting each of the 32 bits to 1 which is the maximum value 4 bytes of memory can represent. `1` is an integer literal which typically takes up 4 bytes of memory too. So you're basically adding 1 to the maximum value 4 bytes can represent. This is how the maximum value looks like in memory:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

When you add one to this, there is no more room to represent one greater than the maximum value and hence all bits are set to 0 and back to their minimum value.
Although you're assigning to a `uint64_t` that has twice the capacity of `uint32_t`, it is only assigned after the addition operation is complete.
The addition operation checks the types of both the left and the right operands and this is what decides the type of the result. If atleast one value were of type `uint64_t`, the other operand would automatically be promoted to `uint64_t` too.
If you do:

```
 (UINT32_MAX) + (uint64_t)1;
```

or:

```
 (unint64_t)(UINT32_MAX) + 1;
```

,
you'll get what you expect. In languages like C#, you can use a `checked` block to check for overflow and prevent this from happening implicitly.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know the overflow would happen at the + thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's not referred to as overflow in the Standard . It's well-defined behaviour and unsigned arithmetic is defined as modular arithmetic

Comment: @M.M thanks :) I have missed it in the standard then :)

Comment: @amal-k can you explain why it is not an issue for `UINT8_MAX` and `UINT16_MAX`

Comment: @Lars Nielsen `int` is (typically) 32 bits. The default type of a numeric literal like `1` is `int`. So when you add `1` to `UINT8_MAX` and `UINT16_MAX`, as the type of `1` is `int`, a larger type, the `UINT8_MAX` and `UINT16_MAX` will be promoted to `int`. If one operand is of a larger size than the other, then the smaller type is promoted to the larger type. If you want the same effect, then you will need to explicitly convert the expression to the smaller type. `(uint8_t)(UINT8_MAX + 1)` and `(uint16_t)(UINT16_MAX + 1)` will evaluate to 0.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that even if both the operands were `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`, like: `(UINT8_MAX + (uint8_t)1)` or `(UINT16_MAX + (uint16_t)1)` , the result will still be promoted to `int`. Any operation on numeric types smaller than `int` will promote the result to `int`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain Amal :)